# OpenLayers v 5.3.0 - get back attribution behavior

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

In new version v 5.3.0 (ol map library)
Changed behavior attribution. Before I had icon "i" and under it all attribution for displayed layers.

[image]

[image]

Now I have some flattened info.

Developers gave instructions to use the previous behavior:

> Attributions are not collapsible for `ol/source/OSM`
>
> When a map contains a layer from a `ol/source/OSM` source, the
>   `ol/control/Attribution` control will be shown with the ``collapsible:
>   false` behavior.
>
> To get the previous behavior, configure the `ol/control/Attribution`
>   control with  `collapsible: true`.

But how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way as `collapsible: false` was specified in previous versions (note that it has always been a terms of use requirement of OSM and some other sources that attributions are always visible when their tiles are used on a public facing site)

```
  import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
  import View from 'ol/View.js';
  import {defaults as defaultControls} from 'ol/control.js';
  import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
  import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';

  var map = new Map({
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      })
    ],
    controls: defaultControls({ attributionOptions: { collapsible: true } }),
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });
```

or if you are using the full build:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  controls: ol.control.defaults({ attributionOptions: { collapsible: true } }),
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks `@Mike` , It was a life saving

Answer (score 0):

Mike I had tried

```
controls: ol.control.defaults({ attributionOptions: { collapsible: true }).extend([ 
new ol.control.FullScreen(), 
new ol.control.ZoomSlider(), 
new ol.control.Zoom(), ... ]),
```

And everything it's ok.
A huge thanks!